# Ping status and return

Tags: linux, windows, perl, ping

I am writing a perl script which issues a ping to a certain IP address, with a ping size of 65000 and count of 1000.

Now when the remote PC is up, things are okay. The ping succeeds and ends after sending 1000 pkts.

However, in case of failure, it always returns `"Destination host unreachable"`. Ping keeps on trying for too long trying to send arp requests/ping  requests before it eventually gives up with a 100% pkt loss string.

My question is, how can I make ping to exit if lets say the initial 100 pings itself do not generate a response. I do not want to wait for too long in case initial pings itself fail. I want ping to exit. How do I do this?

I am currently using Linux for my script. Please let me know how to do this for

- Linux
- Windows.

[Please note the size of the ping pkt can vary. So I want a solution which is independent of the size/count]

Comment: Well, there is a `-W` option for a timeout in the standard `ping` command. I suggest you take a look at the commands manual page: `man ping`

Comment: script which has ping in infinite while loop inside while loop 1 packet ping i.e. count 1, check exit status of ping if not zero, incr a counter, exit after it reaches a predefined count.
you can have -W or -w for ping inside while loop

Comment: What are you trying to prove with 1000 packets of 65000 bytes (= 65 megabytes of useless bandwidth wastage)? I think there's probably an XY problem here...

Comment: @Daylite If the below answer fulfills your needs, please take a moment to check it as the solution.  Currently 32 of your 34 questions have no selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [`Net::Ping`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aPing) module which gives you the flexibility to control individual pings directly from your script.